# JQuery: updating tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip

- I have a tooltip attached to a div.
- the div is also draggable
- on dragstop event i need to change the value of the tooltip. However, since its on dragstop the mouse is still over the div and consequently the title="".

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to accomplish this?

- Shawn

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are saying the tooltip remains open while you are dragging the div around?

If you are using the jQuery tooltip plugin... it makes a div with an ID of "tooltip", so you could just access the tooltip directly to change the data.

```
$('#tooltip').append('new data');
```

I haven't tested it but I don't think the title will update with this new data once you are no longer hovering over the tooltip.

Comment: Why the downvote? This method will work if that is what the poster is asking.